# CSS Container Issue - Background not running full length

Tags: css, background, containers

I'm having issues trying to get my main container (the white background) to stretch to the bottom of the content, it currently runs in the header only.  I've been racking my brains for ages, I've tried adding in a clear and also made sure that all the containers within the main container are floated but still no joy.

This is a live website and can be viewed at http://www.ridermagazine.co.uk

I've also noticed that my sidebar has dropped down below the content instead of displaying on the right-hand side, this lead me to believe that I had gotten my maths wrong but I've double checked everything and nothing seems to be out of place.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

CSS code for container:

```
#page-wrap {
width: 926px; 
margin: 20px auto;
background-color:#fff;
padding:17px;
}
```

Comment: you have to show your CSS code if you wish others to answer

Comment: @awenkhh I've added the code for the container, do you need any more?

Comment: @DaveBurns Try set padding and margin to 0px and tell me what you get?

Comment: You have a serious error in your html, it contains multiple id with the same name content.

Comment: @sємsєм What errors are occuring, can you tell me which id's have the same named content?  Also I set both Margin and Padding to 0 and nothing happened.

Comment: @DaveBurns Just search in your html source for id="content", if you find more one result, it will considered as an error or mistake. Id attribute value should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in using all the float:left directives. You don't need them if all the elements which are block elements are block elements. For example the `h1` element in `header` is NOT a block element. It seems that somewhere is a `h1 {display: inline}` - e.g globally. If you overwrite this in the inspector of your browser to h1 {display: block} the white background "is growing" ;-). So my tip: remove all the float directives and start again with composing.

Remember: float is evil ;-)

Just use it if you really need to. For example if you need two main div elements live next to each other. Also instead think about using overflow ....

EDIT: the error is in div `id="content"`. Remove `float:left` and it works

That's what I mean with evil float elements ;-)

Comment: This has worked but my sidebar is still displaying beneath the content, is that an issue of the floats?  Also many thanks for your help, when I was taught CSS it I was told to always float everything but clearly this isn't the solution :)

Comment: uhh ... float EVERYTHING sounds like dance with the devil ;-). This is imho not the correct way. All elements have a defined behaviour. So have div elements the behaviour display:block. Because one is expecting them to take the full place available but limited by the attribute width. In the case of the navigation placed next to the content on the right side, you have a situation, where you could use float to get both div elements on the same line. But maybe it is a better approach to use display:inline-block for both elements and tell people using IE 6 and 7 to go and get a newer browser ;-)

Comment: I'm still having massive issues with it, I can not get the sidebar to display at the top of the content on the right hand side, it either sits at the bottom or next to the oldest article, it's doing my head in tbh :(

Comment: I wrote together a little gist you can find here: [https://gist.github.com/4055233](https://gist.github.com/4055233)
I hope it helps to figure out how it works ...

Comment: Thanks dude, this'll really help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

at the end of your "page-wrap" div.

Comment: that doesn't have any effect at all I'm afraid.

Comment: It's been fixed now, it was the fact that #content was floated when it didn't need to be, hence why it works now with or without the clear at the end of the wrapper :)

Answer (score 0):

A more accurate answer is

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

as he did not mention if he has a class called clear

"at the end of your "page-wrap" div."

Comment: that's not fixing the problem

Comment: no offense! yes it works - but it is just a fix for a not so good created CSS Stylesheet. The problem lies in the many float:left directives. If you take the time and remove some of them in the CSS inspector of your browser and give block elements (like h1) their 'block' back, you don't need clear:both. It's always a bad idea to add too many "pussy" elements. The div element your are including into the HTML code does not have any info for the page. It's just a workaround and not necessary ... again ... no offense ;-)

Comment: The question wasnt how to tidy up the HTML, it was how to solve the problem simply doing this test [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fridermagazine.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) show's many issues, that need to be addressed but again, thats not the question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in answering my questions guys, the theme I'm working on was actually a HTML5 wireframe so I could try and learn some CSS3 and HTML5.  When I was taught CSS I was told that floats are my friend and that I should always float everything :)  Im not entirely sure why the validator says I'm using a display:inline on the H1 tags as it doesn't appear on the stylesheet itself?

Comment: wait someone actually told you to float everything? They should be shot, dead. that's even worse than telling someone to use tables as a design.

Comment: @Rikoshay yeah he was my old boss at a design studio, I'm primarily a designer, not a coder, and he taught me CSS, he told me everything should be floated (all main elements anyway such as header, content, sideber etc) whenever I ran into an issue his first response was always "Have you tried floating it?"